# javascripts array to convert json php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, parsing

I analyzed the text, how to convert it to json
To use (php) json_decode

json_decode returns a syntax error for this text

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
```

```
{1: {name: '1page',img: 'loc1.png?1'},2: {name: '2page',img: 'KMFBBtkfQ0I.jpg'},3: {name: '3page',img: 'LUbBPtWbWO4.jpg'},4: {name: '4page',img: 'aRbGcm1kHT4.jpg'},5: {name: '5page',img: 'EUp2_8QQuPM.jpg'},6: {name: '6page',img: 'Uv07mXmwcRQ.jpg'},7: {name: '7page',img: 'TKFOhIpPIno.jpg'},8: {name: '8page',img: '7614/M4AEZ27Z7EA.jpg'},9: {name: '9page',img: 'dlRmw2YT5TA.jpg'},10: {name: '10page',img: 'BnxGt0Oq6KQ.jpg'}}
```

Comment: It's not valid JSON as there are no quotes round the key names

Comment: Use a JSON linter online to tell you what's wrong. Use double quotes btw

Comment: I need to convert to a valid format

Comment: Since I get this format from a third-party site

Comment: I suspect your parsing/scraping it from a page, you should look into using [v8js](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php) to JSON.stringify the js object literal, or hack together some regex to mutate it into json https://3v4l.org/9u6CC or just parse out the values with regex https://3v4l.org/QsZRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it to a JSON string  (in your javascript code) like this:

```
$jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
```

And decode it in your php like this:

```
// get the data

// decode here
json_decode($json_data, true)
```

### Update

The above solution is the way to send JSON string from the client JavaScript to your PHP server. But you seem to have a JS object and you want to convert it to JSON in PHP. Here is the solution for this:

```
$temp = "{1: {name: '1page',img: 'loc1''1.png?1'},2: {name: '2page',img: 'KMFBBtkfQ0I.jpg'},3: {name: '3page',img: 'LUbBPtWbWO4.jpg'},4: {name: '4page',img: 'aRbGcm1kHT4.jpg'},5: {name: '5page',img: 'EUp2_8QQuPM.jpg'},6: {name: '6page',img: 'Uv07mXmwcRQ.jpg'},7: {name: '7page',img: 'TKFOhIpPIno.jpg'},8: {name: '8page',img: '7614/M4AEZ27Z7EA.jpg'},9: {name: '9page',img: 'dlRmw2YT5TA.jpg'},10: {name: '10page',img: 'BnxGt0Oq6KQ.jpg'}}";

function jsToJsonStr($str)
{
    $search = array("{ ", " }",  ', ', " ,", " :",  ": ", ":",   ":'",  "':{",  "'}",   "{",    "',",   ",",);
    $replace = array("{", "}",   ',',  ",",  ":",   ":",  "\":", ":\"", "\":{", "\"}",  "{\"",  "\",",  ",\"");

    $str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
    $obj = json_decode($str, true);
    return $obj;
}

$json_str = jsToJsonStr($temp);
var_dump($json_str);
```

This works well on you data.

Comment: Use my site as an intermediary for transformation ?

Comment: @АлександрЛабудов I assumed you were trying to send a json from javascript to your php. You can convert the JSON object in you javascript before sending to PHP this way.

Comment: I get javascript from a third-party site

Comment: @АлександрЛабудов I updated the answer, so that you can convert the JS object you get from third party websites.